# How can i use ClearCanvas in remote database?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, clearcanvas

How can i get data from REMOTE database using OnStart method?

```
 protected override int OnStart(StudyLoaderArgs studyLoaderArgs)
        {
            ApplicationEntity ae = studyLoaderArgs.Server as ApplicationEntity;
            _ae = ae;

            EventResult result = EventResult.Success;
            AuditedInstances loadedInstances = new AuditedInstances();
            try
            {

                XmlDocument doc = RetrieveHeaderXml(studyLoaderArgs);
                StudyXml studyXml = new StudyXml();
                studyXml.SetMemento(doc);

                _instances = GetInstances(studyXml).GetEnumerator();

                loadedInstances.AddInstance(studyXml.PatientId, studyXml.PatientsName, studyXml.StudyInstanceUid);

                return studyXml.NumberOfStudyRelatedInstances;

            } 
            finally 
            {
                AuditHelper.LogOpenStudies(new string[] { ae.AETitle }, loadedInstances, EventSource.CurrentUser, result);
            }
        }
```

---

i need to use OnStart in main project. How cn i use or call OnStart method

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, `OnStart` is an event; if you can provide the `StudyLoaderArgs` some how, then you can move your code in `Init(ApplicationEntity)` method and call it like following:

```
Init(myStudyArgs);
```

and in `OnStart`:

```
protected override int OnStart(StudyLoaderArgs studyLoaderArgs)
{
    Init(StudyLoaderArgs.Server as ApplicationEntity);
}
```

**--EDIT--**

1. Move existing `OnStart()` body in `Init()`

   void Init(ApplicationEntity ae)
   {
       EventResult result = EventResult.Success;
       AuditedInstances loadedInstances = new AuditedInstances();
       try
       {

   ```
       XmlDocument doc = RetrieveHeaderXml(studyLoaderArgs);
       StudyXml studyXml = new StudyXml();
       studyXml.SetMemento(doc);

       _instances = GetInstances(studyXml).GetEnumerator();

       loadedInstances.AddInstance(studyXml.PatientId, studyXml.PatientsName, studyXml.StudyInstanceUid);

       return studyXml.NumberOfStudyRelatedInstances;

   } 
   finally 
   {
       AuditHelper.LogOpenStudies(new string[] { ae.AETitle }, loadedInstances, EventSource.CurrentUser, result);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Call `Init()` from `OnStart()`

   protected override int OnStart(StudyLoaderArgs studyLoaderArgs)
   {
       ApplicationEntity ae = studyLoaderArgs.Server as ApplicationEntity;
       _ae = ae;
       Init(ae);
   }
3. `OnStart()` is an event, and would be called upon service(assuming that it is a service) start. TO be more specific, events are not there to be called, rather events are raised as a notification that something has happened; all we do is handle the event; i.e. register a method as a handler for that event, and then that method will be invoked each time the event is raised.

So, to achieve want you want, you can call `Init()` rather than `OnStart()`; but to call `Init()` you will have to provide the input arguments, which is what my first sentence says - or it'd be something like `OnStart(EventArgs.Empty);`

Not sure if this answers your question, but above the top of my skull! (0:

Comment: @Programmerist: Please see my edit in response to your comment.